# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: No System TLS , while running selenium script in eclipse

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, okhttp

I tried to run simple selenium testcase using Eclipse and I'm getting error below  mentioned.
Then I tried simple example from     https://www.guru99.com/first-webdriver-script.html    , that also doesn't work. It was working previously.

**Selenium jar version: selenium-java-3.13.0** ,Please someone help me on this.

```
Exception in thread "main"java.lang.AssertionError: No System TLS
  at okhttp3.internal.Util.assertionError(Util.java:465)
  at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.systemDefaultTrustManager(OkHttpClient.java:294)
  at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:254)
  at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:935)
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
  at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Seemes there is a KeyStore (file?) referenced which is in bad format or wrongly configured. Please prvoide the fill stack trace.

Comment: @Kishor B show your java code might be you missed adding some import statements or any libraries.